# Is there support for transport 'email' in Web OTP?

Tags: web, browser, one-time-password

According to the specification (https://wicg.github.io/web-otp/) the purpose is to support OTP via email. Is it already supported somehow by implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being considered but there's no concrete implementations exist yet.

Here's the spec being considered: https://github.com/samuelgoto/email-otp

Comment: Do you have any sources I could read regarding this?

Comment: Just added a link to the spec being in consideration. https://github.com/samuelgoto/email-otp